# Draw ofPlanePrimative From Plane Parameters

Tags: math, 3d, openframeworks

I'm looking for a straightforward way to draw a plane as specified by a standard plane equation:

```
ax + by + cz + d = 0
```

I have the plane parameters (`a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`), but I'm having difficulty finding an easy way to draw this plane in OpenFrameworks.

The closest I've gotten is orienting the plane by using `lookAt` to set its normal:

```
ofPlanePrimative plane;
plane.lookAt(ofVec3f(a, b, c));
plane.draw();
```

This orients the plane correctly, but doesn't position it.  When I tried positioning with `plane.setPosition`, it appears to reset the orientation; can't I chain those operations?

I'm sure this is relatively simple 3D vector math, but for some reason I'm struggling with this.  Perhaps I shouldn't be using `ofPlanePrimative`?  Should I be constructing a mesh instead?  Ideally, I would like to draw an infinite plane (perhaps with `of3dUtils::drawGridPlane`).

Any direction would be helpful at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **d** to dolly your plane after the lookAt :

```
ofPlanePrimative plane;
plane.lookAt(ofVec3f(a, b, c));
plane.dolly(d);
plane.draw();
```